# Disallow a User to Create Reports and Dashboards For a Specific Object

Tags: reporting, dashboard, custom-profile

How can I disallow a certain user to create reports and dashboards for a specific custom object?

I already tried profile settings, but there's only this **Create and Customize Reports** permission on system settings. Nothing any object-specific.

For example: User can create reports and dashboards for all objects, except for this object: Custom_object__c.

*Note that user has the ability to create, edit, and delete records for this custom object. His limitation only is that he must not be able to generate reports and dashboards for this object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the object is reportable, and the user has read only access to the object, and the user can create and customize reports, you cannot block access to a specific object for reporting purposes. You can only restrict reporting on the object entirely, or deny read access to a user's profile. You'll need to think about if the user needs the ability to create reports, as that is the only way to prevent reporting on an object for a profile.

Comment: so you mean there's no object-specific settings for reports and dashboards creation?

Comment: @asdfg Not on a per-profile setting, no. Of the several combinations available to you, if a user can create reports, and that object is reportable, you can't stop a user from reporting on the object.

Comment: sad to hear this, but thanks for your clear response